# different build configs and use it in code

Tags: java, netbeans

I was wondering if it is possible to define multiple build configs in Netbeans (Java) and somehow *understand* which build config you are in, in code!

I did this using Visual Studio and C++ long time ago, where I was able to #define something (e.g. #define DEBUG_MODE) in build config and check it using #ifdef(e.g. output some debug info). but I have no idea if this is possible in Java, or particularly in Netbeans.

Comment: You can do something similar using properties files.

Comment: using properties files it would be "run time" not "compile time".

Comment: it's matter because of you may need to define somethings here and there and this kind of stuff and being "run time" will become very annoying since the compiler will say you can't do this or you can't do it.
it is possible to handle this in run time but it is MUCH better in compile time.

Comment: A concrete example might be helpful.